# Why is my ASP.net mvc app no longer running under IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, msbuild

UPDATE: I fixed this by changing to AspNetCoreModule and used out of process.

---

This mvc site has been running for a while but after the last deploy, it will no longer run. The event log shows this error:

`Application <path to app> failed to start. Exception message:
Application DLL was not found at  <path to app>\.\Proxy.dll. Confirm the application dll is present. Single-file deployments are not supported in IIS.`

In the csproj file, I have this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And, I publish to a local folder like so:

`dotnet publish <path to source>/Proxy.csproj -c Release -o ./build -r win10-x64 --self-contained true`

Finally, the web config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers> 
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Proxy.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And, since this ran up until last update, I believe IIS (version 8.5- Win Server 2012 R2) is setup correctly. Under modules, I see AspNetCoreModuleV2. The Apppool is setup with Integrated pipeline and no managed code.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks. Eric

Comment: 1) In process hosting is in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and above. 2) ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework is no longer supported by ASP.NET Core 3.0 and above. So you need to carefully check what's the current runtime used by your web app. ASP.NET Core 2.2 is end of life, so you have to either go back to 2.1, where in process hosting must be off, or go up to 3.1, where you need to fully migrate to .NET Core.

Comment: @LexLi So I changed to AspNetCoreModule and out of process hosting process and it works again. The problem I can't upgrade is because I need WCF.